# Different namespace for xades:QualifyingProperties

Tags: xades4j

When I sign an XML document I get:

```
<xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Target="#xmldsig-0497c0ca-641b-4e41-8ee8-bf223afabea1">
                <xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-0497c0ca-641b-4e41-8ee8-bf223afabea1-signedprops">
....
               </xades:SignedProperties>
</xades:QualifyingProperties>
```

What can I do to get `xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.1.1#"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xades4j is based on version 1.4.1 of XAdES. The namespace can't simply be changed, as the XML structure would be different.

Comment: Can someone suggest a library that supports ETSI v1.1.1 for java?

xades4j is great but as mentioned, it does not support ETSI v1.1.1